# Cloudpage Activity not tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I have a custom preference center that went live a couple weeks ago.  We'll probably start using HotJar for deeper analytics on this page, but I looked this morning at the page activity and had 0's across the board.

Is this a known issue?  Or is there a tracking code I need to add within the page header?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the Cloudpages FAQ:
`CloudPages does not track clicks via Code View and HTML paste content.`